# Regex for String abxba

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex for a problem I found in some lecture notes during self-study. This regex matches strings of the form abxba where x is a string of a’s, b’s, and c’s that does not contain ba as a substring. What I have so far is `^ab(a+c+b+|a+b+c+|b+c+a+|c+a+b+)ba$` but it is obviously incomplete. Could somebody help?

Comment: Is `x` required, or is it acceptable input to have just `abba`?

Comment: It is required and must contain at least one a,b, and c.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: It's not homework - it's self-study from lecture notes. I don't really understand the downvotes.

Comment: @JohnRoberts and y is your regex incomplete

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Because he doesn't understand how to complete it?

Comment: Still don't understand the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
^ab(?!.*ba.*ba$)(?=.*a.*ba$)(?=.*b.*ba$)(?=.*c.*ba$)[abc]+ba$
    ----------- ------------
         |           |->match further only if there's atleast 1 a
         |->match further only if there's no ba
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to write a regex? You could just use `^ab([a-c]*)ba$` to grab the middle of the string and just run some checks on the middle, like making sure it contains at least one a, b, and c and making sure it doesn't contain ba.

EDIT: Better yet, you could skip regex altogether and just do all the above checks, adding checks to make sure it begins with ab and ends with ba.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this regex using a negative lookahead:

```
^ab(a|b(?!a)|c)+ba$
```

It matches this string `abbcabcabbbbcccaaaaaaba` but not this: `abbcabcabbabbcccaaaaaaba`

Comment: It doesn't make sure there's at least one a, b, and c though.

Comment: Right, I missed that comment about the required a, b and c.